# Error install emacs-lucid

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, synaptics, emacs

When I upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 there was one package that was not able to update that was `emacs-lucid`.

When I try to upgrade it now I get the error:

```
dpkg: warning: old emacs-lucid package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
```

And when I try to install or removing software through Ubuntu software I get:

```
E: The package emacs-lucid needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.
```

The second error message started appearing after I install Synaptics. I tried telling it not to upgrade `emacs-lucid` and now I can't update anything.

The output of `apt-cache policy emacs-lucid` was:

```
emacs-lucid:
Installed: 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2
Candidate: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1
Version table:
1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 500
500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
*** 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2 100
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

After running `sudo apt-get install emacs-lucid=1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2` I got:

```
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-lucid : Depends: emacs-bin-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After running `apt-cache policy emacs-bin-common emacs-common` I got:

```
  Installed: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
emacs-common:
  Installed: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Do you have *universe* repository enabled? If not - try to add it again with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`. Then please add output of `apt-cache policy emacs-lucid` to the question.

Comment: I added what you suggested.

Comment: Please to upgrade it directly with `sudo apt-get install emacs-lucid=1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2` and show the errors (if any).

Comment: I got: The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-lucid : Depends: emacs-bin-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy emacs-bin-common emacs-common` to the question.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install emacs-lucid=1:26.3+1-1ubuntu1` directly.

Comment: did not work I just get a bunch of errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101658/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-budget-tech).